# REST API push update to other except sender using socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am currently using express REST API to update my database and then push the update to the other relevant users that needs to be notified, except the sender.

I know in socket io documentation [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet/) , it says you can use

```
// to all clients in room1 except the sender
socket.to("room1").emit(/* ... */);
```

but in express REST API, you lose the context of which `socket` this sender is belongs to.
I can fix it partially by letting all users that connected to server to join its own room identified by user ID

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.join("user:johndoe123");
});
```

so that when I need to push update to others except sender, I can just

```
io.to("some room").except("user:johndoe123").emit("some event");
```

Note: that the user ID is retrieved from JWT token in REST API request header.

To update the sender, I can just return the API response.

However this does not update to other session, for example if the same user browse with two devices, first device perform update by calling REST API to the server. First device received update from the API response. Other users are also notified by the socket io. But second device does not receive this update because its using the same user ID (joined the same room, "user:johndoe123").

Is there any workaround for this?

Or is performing update using REST API is just a bad idea and I should just use socket io method by emitting update event, so that I can have the `socket` object?

Or should I just pass the socket io session ID to REST API request header? so that I can retrieve the `socket` object using the session ID in REST API. but I'm not sure if this is a good practice, [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#usage-of-the-socketid-attribute)

Comment: Using the socketID sounds ok in your case since you are okay with the caveats mentioned in the socket.io page. In fact, you actually do want an ephemeral ID since you're firing one-time updates to all connections, not to all users. Another idea is to take your express server's backend code for this endpoint and make it into a function that can be used in both a REST endpoint and a socket.io handler. Then you can allow the user to do either the REST API call or the socket.io API call, thus maintaining your same REST API but adding the socket update functionality when it's called via the socket.

Comment: Not sure with Socket.io, but in [PieSocket](https://piesocket.com) you can use `notifySelf=0` to send messages to all users except the sender.

More info: https://www.piesocket.com/docs/3.0/websocket-api

Maybe there is some simmilar config you can find for [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/)